Can husband divorce during menses?
Is it correct that in Islam divorce can not be given during wife's menstrual period? I would like some reference.

Giving divorce during menstrual bleeding is against the sunnah and is haram. One should give a divorce when the woman is in a pure state and when the husband has not copulated with her since the end of her last menstrual period.
According to the view of the majority, despite being sinful, such a divorce takes effect and is counted as a valid divorce. However the view of a minority including Ibn Taymiyah (and some modern salafi scholars), the Zahiris and Shias is that it is invalid and does not take effect.
The evidence for this includes:

أن عبد الله بن عمر، أخبره أنه، طلق امرأته وهى حائض، فذكر عمر للنبي صلى الله عليه وسلم، فتغيظ فيه رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ثم قال ‏‏ ليراجعها، ثم ليمسكها حتى تطهر، ثم تحيض فتطهر، فإن بدا له أن يطلقها فليطلقه
Narrated Abdullah bin `Umar:
That he had divorced his wife during her menses. `Umar mentioned that to the Prophet.
Allah's Apostle became angry and said, "He must take her back (his wife) and keep her with him till she becomes clean from her menses and then to wait till she gets her next period and becomes clean again from it and only then, if he wants to divorce her, he may do so."
— Bukhari and Muslim


عن ابن عمر، قال حسبت على بتطليقة
Narrated Ibn `Umar:
(Divorcing my wife during her menses) was counted as one legal divorce.
— Bukhari

The anger of the Prophet ﵌ is evidence that the act was haram. The fact that he told him to take her back (revoke the divorce) is evidence that a valid divorce had occurred.
Among its wisdom is that divorce during menses is harder for the woman as her waiting period gets longer.
Note that the above applies to divorce after consummation of marriage. Also according to the majority it does not apply to khula' where the wife asks for divorce.
Ref:

أجمعت الأمة على تحريم طلاق الحائض الحائل بغير رضاها فلو طلقها أثم ووقع طلاقه ...  وشذ بعض أهل الظاهر
The Ummah has a consensus that divorcing a menstruating woman without her consent is prohibited. If the husband divorces her, he commits a sin but the divorce takes place ... and some Zahiris deviated
— Sharah Nawawi

